# Відповідник до "дитячого садка"

Tags: відповідник, діалектизми

Нещодавно стало цікаво чи є українській відповідник до слова "дитсадок" (дитячий садок). І одразу ж на Вікіпедії я наткнувся на діалектний варіант "[захоронка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)". Однак, такого слова немає в СУМі, на Словотворі схожої теми мені знайти не вдалося.

Цікавить, чи є ще якісь українські слова, які б вживалися для позначення дошкільних закладів освіти (можливо діалектизми з інших регіонів України, якщо там взагалі існувало так поняття як "дитячий садок")?

Comment: Але ж і _дитина_, і _сад_ — слова праслов'янського походження.

Comment: А чи не може це бути скалькованим перекладом німецького "Kindergarten" (подаю інформацію з Вікіпедії, бо не зміг знайти походження цього слова в ЕСУМі)?

Comment: Так і є. Просто окремі слова українські — і на мою думку, калька не є чимось принципово поганим, це просто один із способів творення нових слів/конструкцій у мові. Але так, в такому ракурсі питання, звісно, має сенс.